# Number of tests run simultaneously in Katalon

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

How many tests can run simultaneously in Katalon Studio?

Recommended min configuration requires 1GHz CPU and 2GB RAM. When I run tests on my 16GB computer, I didn't notice any issues when running 5-6 shorter tests (about 1 min long) at the same time. But when running two parallel tests that go on for 20 minutes or more, I begin to see hick-ups.

Is there a pre-set limit on number of test running simultaneously?

Comment: Keep in my that we should rather use automation tests for testing single functionalities, we'll get then quick answer which of the tests passes and which not. Automating long path tests, that are passing through many parts of application, makes that the tests last longer and their getting more unstable, as there are many places where Your test can fail, and then You have to repeat the whole time consuming test once again.

Comment: I know Katalon Studio isn't ment for performance testing, it is just that I have some tests that take longer.

Comment: I haven't dealt with Katalon Studio previously, but for the instance JMeter which is nice and easy tool for performance tests, can be run both in GUI and non-GUI mode (the second mode is recommended way though as it consumes less resources), maybe there's something similiar in the Katalon Studio?

Comment: Thanks. I know there is a headless mode option in Katalon. I'm using it regularly. I would still like to know the limits, though..

Comment: If You're running out of memory, You can just try to increase the amount of virtual memory using Your HDD space as a RAM.

Comment: I've tried to run tests that run perfectly fine sequentially in parallel and while my machines not a beast, I would expect it to be able to run them. However that's not the case. Have you considered running them in docker containers?

Comment: @lloyd Were your test long? When I run tests that run for about one minute they run just fine, but the problem is when running longer tests (15-20 mins) in parallel.

Comment: My tests take about 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that, starting with Katalon Studio version [5.10.1](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/new/version-5101.html), users can set the number of concurrent execution when running Test Suites in Test Suite Collection.

[image]

Max setting is 1000, but I guess very few people are going to run that many Test Suites in parallel.